# Date Time format mixed and separate to two columns and change the format of date

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have data that contains date and time in a single columns. The format is mixed of date and time. That means, date in some rows and time in some rows in the same column. I have created a simple example to illustrate my problem. The following is the sample data frame:

```
data = pd.DataFrame ()
data ['Date'] = ['Saturday 20th April 2019','12:30:00','12:30:00','15:00:00']
data ['Name'] = ['A','B','C','D']
```

I want to do two things.

1. I want to separate date and time into two different columns.
2. I want to change the format of date to 20-04-2019.

The expected output is as follows:

[image]

Date1 and Time are the  new columns that I wanted to create.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way

```
data['Date1']=pd.to_datetime(data.Date)
data['Time']=data['Date1'].dt.time
s=data.Date.str.contains(':')
data['Date1']=data['Date1'].mask(s).ffill()
data['Time']=data['Time'].where(s).bfill()
data
Out[1002]: 
                       Date Name      Date1      Time
0  Saturday 20th April 2019    A 2019-04-20  12:30:00
1                  12:30:00    B 2019-04-20  12:30:00
2                  12:30:00    C 2019-04-20  12:30:00
3                  15:00:00    D 2019-04-20  15:00:00
```

Comment: Thanks Wen-Ben. Appreciate your help

Comment: Hi Wen-Ben,
When I worked with my data, it showed me the following error:

TypeError: <class 'datetime.time'> is not convertible to datetime

Comment: @Zephyr do  `df.Date=df.Date.astype(str)` before running above

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
data['Date1'] = data['Date'].str.split(n=1).str[1].ffill()
data['Time1'] = data['Date'].str.extract('(\d+:\d+:\d+)', expand=False).bfill()

print (data)

                       Date Name            Date1     Time1
0  Saturday 20th April 2019    A  20th April 2019  12:30:00
1                  12:30:00    B  20th April 2019  12:30:00
2                  12:30:00    C  20th April 2019  12:30:00
3                  15:00:00    D  20th April 2019  15:00:00
```

Comment: Thanks Jez. Appreciate your help